# Two Spinners Populated By Same ArrayList

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

So I am trying to populate two Spinners in the same Fragment, both using the same list, but to display different items.

I have the following data class:

```
data class ProductTypeObject (

    //ProductType fields (2 fields)
    var productType: String = "",
    var productGroup: String = "",

    @ServerTimestamp
    var dateEditedTimestamp: Date? = null,

    @Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude
    var productTypeID: String = ""

) : Serializable {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return productType
    }
   
}
```

The Spinner is populated in the Fragment when the list is observed from the ViewModel as below:

```
        // Observe ProductTypes and populate Spinner
        businessViewModel.allAppDataProductTypes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { productTypeArrayList ->
            if (!productTypeArrayList.isNullOrEmpty()){
                val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, productTypeArrayList)
                binding.inventoryAddEditProductGroupSpinner.adapter = adapter
            }
        })
```

This shows a list of `product types as I have specified this in the` toString()`of the object, but is there a way to direct a second Spinner to show a list of`product group?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to retrieve the values from the spinners, it's easiest to map the values to a new list:

```
businessViewModel.allAppDataProductTypes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { productTypeArrayList ->
    if (!productTypeArrayList.isNullOrEmpty()){
        //...

        val adapter2 = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
            productTypeArrayList.map(ProductTypeObject::productGroup)
        //...
    }
})
```

If you need both Spinners to be able to retrieve the original item type, then you can't use the ArrayAdapter class as is, since it relies purely on the `toString()` of your class. You can subclass it like this for a more flexible version that lets you pass property or lambda that is used instead of `toString()`. I didn't test it, but I think it will do what you want. If you use this class, you don't need to override `toString()` in your original data class.

```
class CustomArrayAdapter<T : Any>(
    context: Context,
    items: List<T>,
    val itemToCharSequence: T.() -> CharSequence = Any::toString
) : ArrayAdapter<T>(context, 0, items) {
    
    private val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return (convertView ?: inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false))
            .apply {
                val item = getItem(position)!! // will never be null inside getView()
                (this as TextView).text = itemToCharSequence(item)
            }
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
val typeAdapter = CustomArrayAdapter(requireContext(), productTypeArrayList, ProductTypeObject::productType)
val groupAdapter = CustomArrayAdapter(requireContext(), productTypeArrayList, ProductTypeObject::productGroup)
```

Comment: Many tanks Tenfour04 - some interesting options.  I will probably need either or both of these further into my app, but I may create a separate data class and list on this occasion and access the toString().